# What is causing android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException when i'm using an ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android

Hi guys i'm getting this error and i don't know anymore, i've tried and failed, can you please help me out:)
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

```
package com.example.rootx;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ThreeColumn_ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<User> users;
    private int mViewResourceId;

    public ThreeColumn_ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<User> users){
        super(context,textViewResourceId,users);
        this.users = users;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public View getView(int positions, View convertView, ViewGroup parents){
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId,null);

        User user = users.get(positions);

        if(user != null){
            TextView newEntry = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout);
            TextView newEntry2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout2);
            TextView newEntry3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout3);

            if(newEntry != null){
                newEntry.setText((user.getNewEntry()));
            }
            if(newEntry2 != null){
                newEntry2.setText((user.getNewEntry2()));
            }
            if(newEntry3 != null){
                newEntry3.setText((user.getNewEntry3()));
            }

        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

here is my and don't know where the error lies

```
mainpackage com.example.rootx;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    Button btnAdd,btnView;
    EditText EditText1,EditText2,EditText3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        EditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText2);
        EditText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText3);
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnView);
        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);


        btnView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewListContents.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String newEntry = EditText1.getText().toString();
                String newEntry2 = EditText2.getText().toString();
                String newEntry3 = EditText3.getText().toString();
                if(EditText1.length() != 0 && EditText2.length() != 0 && EditText3.length() != 0){
                    AddData(newEntry, newEntry2, newEntry3);
                    EditText1.setText("");
                    EditText2.setText("");
                    EditText3.setText("");
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter all fields",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    public void AddData(String newEntry, String newEntry2, String newEntry3){
        boolean insertData = myDB.addData(newEntry, newEntry2, newEntry3);

        if (insertData == true){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Successfully Entered!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

and my list view

```
package com.example.rootx;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ViewListContents extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    ArrayList<User> userList;
    ListView listView;
    User user;

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewcontents_layout);

        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        userList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data = myDB.getListContents();
        int numRows = data.getCount();

        if(numRows == 0){
            Toast.makeText(ViewListContents.this, "Database is empty!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                user = new User(data.getString(1),data.getString(2),data.getString(3));
                userList.add(user);
            }
            ThreeColumn_ListAdapter adapter = new ThreeColumn_ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_adapter_view,userList);
            listView =  (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        /*listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String name = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Log.d("You clicked on an item", name);
                Cursor data = myDB.getID(myDB.COL2);
                int itemID = -1;
                while(data.moveToNext()){
                    itemID = data.getInt(0);
                }
                if(itemID > -1){
                    Toast.makeText(ViewListContents.this, "Clicked item ID is:",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(ViewListContents.this, EditList.class);
                    editScreenIntent.putExtra("id", itemID);
                    editScreenIntent.putExtra("ITEM1",name);
                    startActivity(editScreenIntent);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(ViewListContents.this, "No ID Associated with that name.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }
        });*/
    }
}
```

hopefully you guys can help me, please tell me if i should post some more code

Comment: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:` show full error log

Comment: You forgot to set `mViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;` in `ThreeColumn_ListAdapter`'s constructor.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow :) `Please help me solve this error, i've tried and failed, android studio` this isn't a useful question title, remember - others in future might have the same issue, so you should make your titles descriptive enough so that they can appear in searches

Comment: Alright I'm fairly new, will do that definitely! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not showing any data think the list has a problem